# renaming default python-unittest function names

Tags: python, python-2.6, unittest2

python's unittest testrunner looks for setUpModule() defined in a file to perform before running any test specified in the module. is there a way to use a decorator or some other tool inorder to rename the function name?

for example:

```
@somedecorator
def globalSetUp():...
```

will enable unittest's loader to recognize this function as the setUpModule function.

i am usint python2.6 with unittest2 package.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just rename/alias the function?

```
def globalSetUp():
    ...

setUpModule = globalSetUp
```

It's just a single additional line, just like a decorator would be.

Answer (score 1):

Derive from `TestCase`, and in your subclass call your own setup function in the `setUp` method. Then create your classes from this new subclass rather than `TestCase`, and you'll have the desired functionality.